# understanding sql query 'distinct' beginner

Tags: mysql

Original table named Employee shows as follow:

```
------------------------
   Id      |     Salary
------------------------
    1       |     100
------------------------
    2       |      100
------------------------
```

**query1 :**`select distinct *  from Employee order by Salary desc limit 1,1;`

**result show:**

```
------------------------
   Id      |     Salary
------------------------
    2      |     100
------------------------
```

**query2** : `select distinct Salary  from Employee order by Salary desc limit 1,1;`

**result show:**

> empty set;

how to understand these two sql queries? I always think result of the query2 will be like this?

```
------------------------
      Salary
------------------------
      100
------------------------
```

any one can give me some suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first query will return `DISTINCT *`, distinct combinations of id and salary which you have two i.e. two rows: `1, 100` & `2, 100`. The use of `LIMIT 1, 1` limits the result to 1 record starting from `OFFSET` 1 so you get the second record as a result of first query

The second query will return `DISTINCT salary` which you have only one i.e. `100`. The use of `LIMIT 1,1` again tries to limit result to 1 record starting from `OFFSET` 1 but as there is only one record to begin with, there is no record at the second offset, hence the empty set.

Check the LIMIT section on this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html